# How to debug segmentation fault in C for the following code..I have used malloc and free in many functions as well as main

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

Basically this is a C code for Oil Well challenge from hackerrank website (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/oil-well). I am getting segmentation fault or abort called when I submit this code.(It is working sometime in my system compiler).

Can someone tell me how to rectify this problem?. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int *min, c, r, q = 0;

void findmin()
{
    int i, minimum = min[0];
    for (i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        if (min[i] > minimum)
            minimum = min[i];
    }
    printf("%d", minimum);
}

void calculate(int a[], int r)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    int *x, *y;
    x = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    y = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    for (i = 0; i <= r; i++)
    {
        x[i] = a[i] % c;
        y[i] = a[i] / c;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= r; i++)
    {
        if ((x[i] - x[i - 1]) > (y[i] - y[i - 1]))
            sum = sum + (x[i] - x[i - 1]);
        else
            sum = sum + (y[i] - y[i - 1]);
    }
    min[q] = sum;
    q++;
    free(x);
    free(y);
}

void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void permute(int a[], int l, int r)
{
    int i;
    if (l == r)
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= r; i++)
            calculate(a, r);
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
        {
            swap((a + l), (a + i));
            permute(a, l + 1, r);
            swap((a + l), (a + i));
        }
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k = 0;
    scanf("%d%d", &r, &c);
    int *arr;
    arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * r * c);
    int **x = (int **) malloc(r * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
        x[i] = (int *) malloc(c * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            scanf("%d", &x[i][j]);

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            if (x[i][j] == 1)
            {
                arr[k] = c * i + j;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    /*printf("Content of arr array is:\n");
     for(i=0;i<k;i++)
     printf("%d \n",arr[i]);
     */

    min = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * r * c);
    permute(arr, 0, k - 1);
    findmin();

    free(arr);
    free(x);
    free(min);
}
```

Updated code(With all the suggestions and answers taken into account )

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int *min,c,r,q=0;
void findmin()
{
    int i,minimum=min[0];
    /*printf("\nmin array is \n");
    for(i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",min[i]);
    }*/
    for(i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        if(min[i]<minimum)
        minimum=min[i];
    }
    printf("%d",minimum);
}
void calculate(int a[],int r)
{
    int sum=0;
    int i;
    int *x,*y;
    x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*r+1);
    y = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*r+1);
    for(i=0;i<=r;i++)
    {
        x[i]=a[i]%c;
        y[i]=a[i]/c;
    }
    for(i=1;i<=r;i++)
    {
        if(abs(x[i]-x[i-1])>abs(y[i]-y[i-1]))
            sum=sum+abs(x[i]-x[i-1]);
        else
            sum=sum+abs(y[i]-y[i-1]);
    }
    min[q]=sum;
    q++;

    free(x);
    free(y);
    //printf("I am here also");
}
void swap(int *x,int *y)
{
    int temp;
    temp=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=temp;
}
void permute(int a[],int l,int r)
{
    int i;
    if(l==r)
    {
    for(i=0;i<=r;i++)
    //printf("%d ",a[i]);
    calculate(a,r);
    //printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=l;i<=r;i++)
        {
            swap((a+l),(a+i));
            permute(a,l+1,r);
            swap((a+l),(a+i));
        }
    }

}

int main(){
    int i,j,k=0;
    scanf("%d%d",&r,&c);
    int *arr;
    arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*r*c); 
    int **x = (int **)malloc(r * sizeof(int *));
    for (i=0; i<r; i++)
         x[i] = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    scanf("%d",&x[i][j]);

    /*for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    printf("%d ",x[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
    }*/


    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
    if(x[i][j]==1)
    {
        arr[k]=c*i+j;
        k++;
    }
    }       
    }
    //printf("Content of arr array is:\n");
    //for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    //printf("%d \n",arr[i]);
    //printf("\nCalling permutation\n");

    min = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*r*c); 
    permute(arr,0,k-1);
    //printf("\nFinding min call\n");
    findmin();

    free(arr);
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) 
    { 
    free(x[i]);
    } 
    free(x);
    free(min);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) `min[i]>minimum` --> `min[i]<minimum`

Comment: use gdb or similar.

Comment: 2) `x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*3); y = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);` : `3` --> `r+1`

Comment: `free`ing `x` in main should be `for (i = 0; i < r; i++) { free(x[i]);} free(x);`

Comment: All function without parameters should be declared as `(void)` instead of ()

Comment: If you can use C99, use VLA:s to turn the broken array allocations in `calculate()` to `int x[r +  1], y[r + 1];`. Remove the `free()`s, of course.

Answer (score 1):

1. Here do `*(r+1)` rather than `*3`

   ```
   x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
   y = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
   ```
2. Change `min[i] > minimum` to `min[i] < minimum`
3. `free` all the memory you've allocated i.e. from `x[0]` to `x[r]` and `y[0]` to `y[r]`.

   Other than this you're probably all good.

Comment: I have made the suggested changes in my code.Now the  code is perfectly running in my system compiler (Dev C++). But on hackerrank,compiler message is "Abort Called"  and  Error (stderr):"  *** Error in `solution': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000692110 ***  ".

Comment: @BLUEPIXY,@LPs,@Sourav Ghosh Guys please help

Comment: I have posted my updated code in the question itself

Comment: Take r+1 in bracket like *(r+1) in x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*r+1);
    y = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*r+1)

Comment: OP is already calling `free` for each pointer returned from `malloc`.

Comment: He's freeing everything but he's not allocating enough memory to accommodate r+1 ints. He's allocating memory for r ints +1 byte which is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating `(r * sizeof (int)) + 1` bytes,

```
x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*r+1);
y = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*r+1);
```

but your loop accesses `r+1` `int` objects:

```
for(i=0;i<=r;i++)
{
    x[i]=a[i]%c;
    y[i]=a[i]/c;
}
```

Correct the behaviour based on whatever your intent is - I suspect you want to allocate `(r + 1) * sizeof (int)` bytes.